# I have 3 Div, how to select 2 div with a click (one by one) and to display none (or other) the third one in Javascript

Tags: javascript, show

i have 3 div (class) in my html and i want with a "addEventListener click" hide the third div when two div has been clicked. Then i have the two cliked div in sort of visibility mod "on" and the one not clicked visibility mod "off"

My actual html structure code :

```
<div class="card" id="card01">

</div>


<div class="card" id="card02">

</div>


<div class="card" id="card03">

</div>
```

And my JS:

```
let pokemons = document.getElementsByClassName("card");
//console.log(pokemons.length);

    for(let i = 0 ; i < (pokemons.length) ; i++){

        pokemons[i].addEventListener('click',function(){



        });

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by adding a "clicked" class to each div that is clicked, and then checking to see if 2 divs have been clicked. Then you can hide the div which has not been clicked by selecting the divs that don't have the "clicked" class.

```
pokemons[i].addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  event.target.classList.add("clicked");
  let clicked = document.getElementsByClassName("clicked");
  if (clicked.length === 2) {
    document.querySelector(".card:not(.clicked)").hidden = true;
  }
});
```

```js
let pokemons = document.getElementsByClassName("card");
for (let i = 0; i < (pokemons.length); i++) {
  pokemons[i].addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    event.target.classList.add("clicked");
    let clicked = document.getElementsByClassName("clicked");
    if (clicked.length === 2) {
      document.querySelector(".card:not(.clicked)").hidden = true;
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.card {
  background-color: gold;
  height: 10em;
  width: 7em;
  margin: 1em;
  float: left;
  padding: 1em;
}

.card::after {
  content: attr(id);
}
```

```html
<div class="card" id="card01">
</div>

<div class="card" id="card02">
</div>

<div class="card" id="card03">
</div>
```

Comment: Hello very thank you for your help, i tryed this code on my codepen sandbox and then it worked fine except when i added a fourth card (mean a fourth div) it hide just one card and not two as expected. 

https://codepen.io/Yirzaraji/pen/PoqZGRz
Any ideas ? Thanks :)

Comment: @Yirzaraji, your CodePen example works as expected for me. Two cards are hidden.